# Solving an ODE without a Lipschitz condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\phi$ be a non-negative function supported on a finite interval. I am trying to construct a solution to the ODE $u''(x) = 2\phi(x) u(x)$. If $u$ were Lipschitz, we could use the Picard-Lindelof theorem. However, I do not see a way to prove the existence of a solution without this hypothesis. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Lipschitz condition is not required for the existence of the solution. Continuity is enough.

Comment: We should be careful when we are using the terminology of certan subject. $u$ is a solution of the DE, so saying $u$ is Lipschitz does not make sense. If you hav an IVP: $u'=f(x, u)$, $u(x_0)=u_0$, you can use the Lipschitz property for $f(x, u)$ not for $u4. For your problem, look at the Peano existence theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given second order differential equation is equivalent with the system
$$\left.\eqalign{u'& =v\cr  v'&=2\phi(x)\ u\cr}\ \right\}\qquad (a<x<b)\ .\tag{1}$$
When $\phi$ is continuous on $\ ]a,b[\ $ then it is locally bounded on this interval, and this suffices to guarantee the "locally Lipschitz with respect to ${\bf y}$"-condition on the domain $\Omega:=\ ]a,b[\ \times{\mathbb R}^2$.

As the system $(1)$ is linear one can even say more: Any solution $x\mapsto\bigl(u(x),v(x)\bigr)$ lives on the whole interval $\ ]a,b[\ $.

Answer (score 1):

- If $\phi$ is continuous, the Peano existence theorem applies.
- Without continuity, the [Carathéodory existence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_existence_theorem) applies, provided $\phi$ is a locally integrable function.

But since you mention $\phi$ being nonnegative, I suspect that you may want to take the variational approach: minimize the functional
$$\mathcal I(u)=\int (u'(x)^2+2\phi(x)u(x)^2)\,dx$$ 
over all $H^1$ functions defined on some interval, with some boundary conditions. The nonnegativity of $\phi$ ensures that $\mathcal I$ is convex, hence lower semicontinuous in the weak topology. Since $\mathcal I$ it also bounded from below (it's nonnegative), it attains its minimum on some function $u^*$. The [Euler-Lagrange equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) says that $u^*$ satisfies the ODE $u'=2\phi u$.

The variational approach does not even require $\phi$ to be locally integrable. It suffices to assume that it's measurable, nonnegative, and that $\mathcal I(u)<\infty$ for at least one $u$ in the function class under consideration. The implication is that any function with finite $\mathcal I$, and in particular the minimizer $u^*$, will turn to $0$ in the right places to offset the nonintegrability of $\phi$.